# Isomorphism between extension modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $(R,\frak m)$ be a Noetherian commutative local ring and $M,N$ and $K$ are $R$-modules. We denote the $i$-th derived functor of $Hom_R(-,-)$ by $Ext_R^i(-,-)$. This notions are well-known, however are introduced in "**An Introduction to Homological Algebra**" by Joseph J. Rotman.

My questions:

$1)$ Is there any condition to let us to write the $$Ext_R^i(M,Hom_R(N,K))\cong Ext_R^i(\mbox{some any module},K)?$$

$2)$ If injective dimension of $K$ (the  least length between all injective resolutions of $K$) is finite, is there any condition to injective dimension of $Hom_R(-,K)$ be finite?

Comment: If $N$ is flat, then $M \otimes N$ works. In general, if $L_{\cdot} \rightarrow M$ is a projective resolution, then the Ext group is the cohomology of $\mathrm{Hom}_R(L_{\cdot} \otimes N, K)$.

Comment: What do you mean by injective dimension of the functor? That its derived functors vanish starting from a certain degree? That’s obvious if $K$ has finite injective dimension (because these derived functors are Ext). That any $Hom(N,K)$ has finite injective dimension? I believe this should hold if $N$ has finite projective dimension, but I don’t think it can work in the rest of the cases (even if $K$ is actually injective, because our Ext groups should recover $Hom(Tor_i(M,N),K)$). There might be a more general spectral sequence too. PS: please avoid editing in new questions.